# Gstreamer, black screen on recording the video

Tags: c, gstreamer, gstreamer-1.0

I have an gstreamer application written in C. It consists of two parts of pipeline.
The first one is for streaming the image from webcam to the screen (let's say "main" part):

```
gst-launch-1.0 -e v4l2src device=/dev/video4 ! video/x-bayer,format=grbg,depth=8,width=800,height=600 ! \
bayer2rgbneon ! video/x-raw,width=800,height=600 ! videoconvert ! tee name=t \
t. ! queue ! kmssink driver-name=imx-drm force-modesetting=false can-scale=false sync=false
```

The second one is for recording video (let's say "recording" part):

```
t. ! queue v4l2h264enc ! h264parse ! \
splitmuxsink next-file=key-frame location=/mnt/video/a%d.mp4 muxer-factory=mp4mux index=1 send-keyframe-requests=TRUE
```

I run the "main" part of the pipeline and on the fly attach/detach "recording" part by hitting the button on the keyboard.

In common - it works fine, but I faced with one issue.
When I attach the "recording" part at the first time - I have the black screen for a couple of seconds.
The next attaching/detaching process does not have such affect.

Does anyone knows what the reason of such issue?

I can provide necessary parts of code if you need.

Answer (score 0):

Going through multiple threads on GStreamer, I found out that the consumer gets resumed before the GStreamer process has fully started. So, it is a practice that is followed to wait for the GStreamer process to completely start and then resume the consumers (Consumers here are your video producer). So, check in your code if there is timeout used.